# Message reading script shows bot's own messages and loops forever

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I made a script that can show me messages people send and the channels and server they send it in but it sends its own messages and goes on forever until the script is stopped

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    To = client.get_channel('channel_id')
    await client.send_message(To, f"SERVER: {message.server.name} CHANNEL: {message.channel} AUTHOR: {message.author.name} MESSAGE: {message.content}")
```

I expect it to send the message, channel, server and the person who sent the message to a channel in my server (which it does well) but it should not show its own message it just sent as this makes it loop forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to stop that, something like

```
if message.author == client.user:
        return
```